# Walker trigonometry puzzle

Tags: algorithm, scala, trigonometry

I have been struggling the entire week with what is wrong with my solution to this exercise from a coding platform. At this point it is not about trying to gain points there, but more to understand where am I wrong in my solution/reasoning.

Here's the assignment:

> The walker starts from point O, walks along OA, AB and BC. When he is
>   in C (C will be in the upper half-plane), what is the distance CO?
>   What is the angle tOC in positive degrees, minutes, seconds?
>
> Angle tOA is alpha (here 45 degrees), angle hAB is beta (here 30
>   degrees), angle uBC is gamma(here 60 degrees).
>
> Task function solve(a, b, c, alpha, beta, gamma) with parameters
>
> a, b, c: positive integers in units of distance alpha, beta, gamma:
>   positive integers in degrees (positive angles are anticlockwise)
>   returns an array
>
> first element: distance CO (rounded to the nearest integer) then angle
>   tOC with the third following elements: second element of the array:
>   number of degrees in angle tOC (truncated positive integer) third
>   element of the array: number of minutes in angle tOC (truncated
>   positive integer) fourth element of the array: number of seconds in
>   angle tOC (truncated positive integer)

And here is a small image demonstrating the stated above:
[image]

Basically each step creates a rectangular triangle. My approach was to use a sine rule to progressively find coordinates of A,B and C, after which finding CO and angle COt would be easy. I am getting the right CO segment according to the test, but the angle seems to be wrong:

```
Test Failed
Expected Array(15, 135, 49, 18), but got Array(15, 143, 2, 45)
```

and

```
Test Failed
Expected Array(20, 141, 4, 23), but got Array(20, 139, 51, 47)
```

Below I paste my solution and the site provided test cases:

```
object Walker {

  case class Point(x: Double, y: Double){
    def moveLeft(by: Double) = Point(by - x, y)
    def moveRight(by: Double) = Point(by + x, y)
    def moveUp(by: Double) = Point(x, by + y)
    def moveDown(by: Double) = Point(x, by - y)
    def inverse() = Point(y, x)
  }

  implicit def roundUp(d: Double): Int = math.ceil(d).toInt

  def solve(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, alpha: Int, beta: Int, gamma: Int): Array[Int] = {
    val pointA = pointHypotenuse(a, alpha)
    val pointB = pointHypotenuse(b, beta).inverse().moveLeft(pointA.x).moveUp(pointA.y)
    val pointC = pointHypotenuse(c, gamma).moveLeft(pointB.x).moveDown(pointB.y)
    val coHypotenuse: Int = math.sqrt(math.pow(pointC.x, 2) + math.pow(pointC.y, 2))
    val sinC = math.sin(math.abs(pointC.x)/coHypotenuse)
    val tOC = 180 - sinC.toDegrees
    coHypotenuse +: degrees(tOC)
  }

  def pointHypotenuse(coteHypotenuse: Int, angleHypotenuse: Int): Point = {
    val sinDuAngle = math.sin(math.toRadians(angleHypotenuse))
    val coteOppose = sinDuAngle * coteHypotenuse
    Point(math.sqrt(math.pow(coteHypotenuse, 2) - math.pow(coteOppose, 2)), coteOppose)
  }

  def degrees(deg: Double): Array[Int] = {
    Stream.iterate((deg.toInt, deg - deg.toInt)){
      case (_, r) =>
        val by60 = r*60
        (by60.toInt, by60 - by60.toInt)
    }.map(_._1).take(3).toArray
  }
}
```

Tests (from the platform):

```
class WalkerTest extends FlatSpec { 
  it should "pass basic tests" in {
    dotest(12, 20, 18, 45, 30, 60, Array(15, 135, 49, 18))
    dotest(15,15,19,50,29,55, Array(12, 133, 18, 44))
    dotest(14,25,17,41,35,59, Array(20, 129, 41, 57))

  }
}

object WalkerTest {
  private def dotest(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, aa: Int, bb: Int, cc: Int, expect: Array[Int]): Unit = {
    val actual: Array[Int] = Walker.solve(a, b, c, aa, bb, cc)
    assertResult(expect){actual}
  }
}
```

I don't think it is a rounding-up error (replacing all Doubles by Ints distances results from the assertions). I wouldn't normally ask this, but I seem to be really blocked on it.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to learn how to debug your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line

```
val sinC = math.sin(math.abs(pointC.x)/coHypotenuse)
```

gets sine of some segment ratio, but this ratio **is cosine** already.
To get an angle, one should use `arccos`

Comment: Thank you @MBo. It is the ratio between OC and Ce (where e is an imaginary point on x axis forming a right angle). Isn't it opposite/hypotenuse? I swapped math.sin... with math.acos... in the line that you mentioned but I am still getting errors (within 1-3 degrees).

Comment: I don't know scala enough, but seems rounding error is accumulating at every step. All calculations should be made in doubles.

Comment: arccos - for x_coordinate//hypotenuse, arcsin - for y-coordinate

Comment: You were right @MBo, but actually the only rounding before calculating the angles was done on `coHypotenuse` once I removed it I started getting exact angles, minutes and seconds, but the CO was sometimes off by 1 - I ridiculously used roundUp instead of math.round. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass angles for `beta(90+given)` and for `gamma(180+given)` as all angles are to be passed taking positive anti-clockwise from `positive x-axis`. Then `moveLeft,moveRight,moveUp,moveDown` and `inverse` functions seems not required. Instead of all of them you can use just one function `moveTo(p:Point)` in case class `Point`, and this modification gives exact test results as shown in scala REPL below:

```
object Walker {
  case class Point(x: Double, y: Double){
    def moveTo(p:Point) = {val t = this.x+p.x;val t1 = this.y+p.y;Point(t,t1) }
  }
  def solve(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double, alpha: Double, beta: Double, gamma: Double):Array[Int]= {
    val pointA = movedPoint(a, alpha)
    val pointB = pointA.moveTo(movedPoint(b,beta))
    val pointC = pointB.moveTo(movedPoint(c,gamma))
    val co = math.sqrt( math.pow(pointC.x, 2) + math.pow(pointC.y, 2))
    val angletOC = Math.asin(math.abs(pointC.y)/co).toDegrees
    val tOC = if(pointC.x<=0 && pointC.y>=0)
        180 - angletOC
    else if(pointC.x<=0 && pointC.y<=0)
        180 + angletOC
    else if(pointC.x>0 && pointC.y<0)
       270 + angletOC
    else angletOC
    Math.round(co).toInt +: convDegMinSec(tOC)
  }
 def movedPoint(dist:Double,angle:Double):Point = {
  val yCo = dist*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))
  val xCo = dist*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))
  Point(xCo,yCo)
 }
 def convDegMinSec(deg: Double): Array[Int] = {
     val degs = deg.toInt
     val mins = (deg - deg.toInt)*60
     val secs =  (mins-mins.toInt)*60
     val arr = Array(degs,mins.toInt,secs.toInt)
     arr
  }
}
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> Walker.solve(12,20,18,45,90+30,180+60)
res58: Array[Int] = Array(15, 135, 49, 18)

scala> Walker.solve(15,15,19,50,90+29,180+55)
res59: Array[Int] = Array(12, 133, 18, 44)

scala> Walker.solve(14,25,17,41,90+35,180+59)
res60: Array[Int] = Array(20, 129, 41, 57)
```